# Django: Operational Error with html template and "no such table"

Tags: python, html, django, database, web

I'm following a tutorial from Obeythetestinggoat.com (Win7, Django 1.11, Python 3.6.1) and having some issues when I try to access the local site manually. When I run `python manage.py runserver` and opening `localhost:8000` in Chrome browser window, I get the following error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user`

The output in the browser windows says that there was an `Error during template rendering`

Here is snippet of template it is trying to render:

```
    <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Superlists</a>
            {% if user.email %}
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="navbar-text">Logged in as {{ user.email }}</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            {% else %}
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" 
                        method="POST" 
                        action="{% url 'send_login_email' %}">
                    <span>Enter email to log in:</span>
                    <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text"/>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </nav>


    {% if messages %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                {% for message in messages %}
                    {% if message.level_tag == 'success' %}
                        <div class="alert alert-success">{{ message }}</div>
                    {% else %}
                        <div class="alert alert-warning">{{ message }}</div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
```

I believe the issue comes from `{% user.email %}` because these specific errors didn't come up until I added them into the template. Although, a few things seem strange about this:

1. All of my functional tests passed without a problem.
2. I didn't have any issues with the `{% messages %}`. Sorry I don't
   know these `{% things %}` are called.
3. `makemigrations` and `migrate` doesn't help.

Here is the `views.py` of the `accounts` app :

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import auth, messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from accounts.models import Token


def send_login_email(request):
    email = request.POST['email']
    token = Token.objects.create(email=email)
    url = request.build_absolute_uri(
        reverse('login') + '?token=' + str(token.uid)
    )
    message_body = f'Use this link to log in:\n\n{url}'
    send_mail(
        'your login link for Superlists',
        message_body,
        'noreply@superlists',
        [email]
    )

    messages.success(
        request,
        "Check your email, we've sent you a link you can use to log in.")
    return redirect('/')

def login(request):
    user = auth.authenticate(uid=request.GET.get('token'))
    if user:
        auth.login(request, user)
    return redirect('/')
```

and here is the `models.py` of the `accounts` app:

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
import uuid

auth.signals.user_logged_in.disconnect(auth.models.update_last_login)

class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    is_anonymous = False
    is_authenticated = True

class Token(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    uid = models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, max_length=40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran a makemigration and a migrate command via the python console? I presume your model changes have not populated to your database yet.

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations your_app_label
```

Then Run

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

You can read more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/

Comment: yea i've tried both and it says that `no changes detected in 'accounts'` and that there are `no migrations to apply`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue at the same section with the same book. While the error pops up in Chrome before login, it will pop up in every browser after login. It's a database issue that only pops up when you're running the server manually.

To fix, use:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

If you have any errors with `migrate`, erase your test database and run the migrations again:

```
rm db.sqlite3
python manage.py migrate --noinput
```